# Unit testing notebooks in databricks

Tags: unit-testing, databricks

I have created test_example.py inside test1 folder  inside repo /Workspace/Repos/temp/test1/sample.py as follow:

```
def test_addition():
    assert 1 + 2 == 3

def test_subtraction():
    assert 5 - 3 == 2
```

I have created sample.py inside test1 folder inside repo /Workspace/Repos/temp/test1/sample.py as follow:
import pytest

```
test_file_path = '/Workspace/Repos/temp/test1/test_example.py'

# Run the test file with the specified arguments
retcode = pytest.main([test_file_path, '-v', '-p', 'no:cacheprovider'])

# Check the return code to see if the tests passed or failed
assert retcode ==0, 'the pytest invocation failed.see the log above for details.'
```

I would like to test all files from test1 folder which have all unit testing files:

but getting error :

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/Workspace/Repos/temp/test1/**pycache**'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_example.py - OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported: '/Worksp...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 1.06s ===============================
Out[2]: <ExitCode.INTERRUPTED: 2>

Comment: From the question I assume we are using pytest for test cases. from a new cell in your notebook run the code `!pytest path_to_test_file.py`

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before calling pytest.main(). And import sys library first.

```
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True
```

This will skip writing pyc files on a readonly filesystem in Databricks.